# Replacing one text character in a word with an image and centering properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website and I am trying to insert this black image in the place of an O in the title, but when I am coding it, the image is not centered and embedded in the middle of the word properly
.
`

```
<section id="home">
    <h1>Pand<img src="assets/webstuff/pandoraxOpng-removebg-preview.png" style="length: 300px; width: 300px; object-position: 5, 5">rax</h1>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 125%">Unleashing your true potential.</p>
  </section>
```

`

[this is what I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaTTf.png)

[this is the result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3DDs.png)

Comment: [Something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/qfu5ykca/)

Comment: Use display flex and set your section flex-direction to column. Then on your h1 element, wrap the text in span tags and then add display flex and add some gap or justify-content to space-between or space-around depending on your spacing, then set the align-items on the flex row (h1 element) as center.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: flex` on the ***section*** and then set the `flex-direction` to **column**. This will make the two elements inside your **section** *stack on top of each other*. Then add `align-items: center` to center the *H1 and P elements* within the **section** element.

```css
#home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <h1>
    <span>Pand</span>
    <img src="assets/webstuff/pandoraxOpng-removebg-preview.png" style="length: 300px; width: 300px; object-position: 5, 5" />
    <span>rax</span>
  </h1>
  <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 125%">Unleashing your true potential.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for such cases. The code is explained in the comments.

```css
.home {
   text-align: center; /* center section */
}

.home h1 {
   font-size: 36px; /* font size - adjust as needed */
   display: flex; /* use flex */
   align-items: center; /* center image vertically */
   justify-content: center;  /* center image horizontally */
}

.home h1 img {
   height: 100px; /* image height - adjust as needed */
   width: 100px; /* image width - adjust as needed */
   margin: 0 5px; /* space between words */
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
    <h1>Pand <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" /> rax</h1>
    <p>Unleashing your true potential.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flexbox, you can create a container, wrap all the text in it and align them all to the center, along with the circle of course.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        body,html {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content:center;
        }

        .container {
            background:red;
            height:80px;
            width:80%;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
        }

        .container .circle {
            width:60px;
            height:60px;
            border-radius:50%;
            background:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hahahaha</h1>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <h1>Hahahaha</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```